# How to update field/formulas in Crystal Reports from another data source?

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have copied text from a stored procedure (SP) in SQL Server and modified it and created a new stored procedure with a new name (Example spMyproc to spMyProc_a). I then updated a report in Crystal Reports that was using the original SP as its data source and substituted the new SP. However, the fields/formulas are still referencing the original SP.

Is there an easy way to remap the fields/formulas to reference my new data source?  Or, will I need to update each one individually?  Also, I cannot expand my new data source in the Field Explorer tree view. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal;

```
1. Select Database Menu
2. Set Datasource Location
3. Choose your current SP
4. Select "Replace with:" SP
5. Select Update and provide any parameters
6. Update the SP name in Field Explorer under Database Fields
```

OR;

In SQL create a dummy SP that executes the actual SP with the same parameter definitions.
In your report use the first SP as the datasource.
When you need to update the actual SP just modify the dummy to call the new SP. As long as the parameters and field definitions are the same there is no need to modify the report otherwise see above.

Comment: Well, I tried setting the datasource location in Crystal, which I was able to do.  However, it would not update the formulas with the new SP name.  Also, I still cannot expand the data source in the Field Explorer tree view.  In SQL, would the dummy SP be the original SP name or the new SP name?  I'm not sure I will be able to make that work with the application.  Thanks.

Comment: In SQL the dummy would be the original SP name and act as a pass-through for the data. Of course you could always just rename the original SP in SQL by adding "_old" to the name and reuse the original SP name as long as the resulting field names and data types have not changed.